# What is the alternative in Harmony OS for TypedArray in Android?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In my project I want to retrieve the color value for the custom attributes at index. Like in android we have the `TypedArray` to do this functionality.

```
final TypedArray typedArray = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomCalendarView, 0, 0);
calendarBackgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomCalendarView_calendarBackgroundColor, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
calendarTitleBackgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomCalendarView_titleLayoutBackgroundColor, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
calendarTitleTextColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomCalendarView_calendarTitleTextColor, getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
weekLayoutBackgroundColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.CustomCalendarView_weekLayoutBackgroundColor, getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
typedArray.recycle();
```

So we don't have `TypedArray` in Harmony OS. What is the way of doing this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need **TypedArray** to retrieve custom attributes from AttributeSet in HarmonyOS, instead **AttrSet** API directly allows you to retrieve custom attributes.

```java
    indicatorNormalColor = mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_NORMAL_COLOR).isPresent() ?
            mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_NORMAL_COLOR).get().getColorValue() : defaultIndicatorNormalColor;
    indicatorSelectedColor = mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_SELECTED_COLOR).isPresent() ?
            mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_SELECTED_COLOR).get().getColorValue() : defaultIndicatorSelectedColor;
    indicatorStrokeColor = mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_STROKE_COLOR).isPresent() ?
            mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_STROKE_COLOR).get().getColorValue() : defaultIndicatorStrokeColor;
    indicatorNormalStrokeWidth = mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_NORMAL_STROKE_WIDTH).isPresent() ?
            mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_NORMAL_STROKE_WIDTH).get().getDimensionValue() : defaultIndicatorNormalStrokeWidth;
    indicatorSelectedStrokeWidth = mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_SELECTED_STROKE_WIDTH).isPresent() ?
            mAttrSet.getAttr(INDICATOR_SELECTED_STROKE_WIDTH).get().getDimensionValue() :
```